# Scheduled actions to scale out/scale in on GCP GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling

I'm pretty new in GCP and wonder how can I schedule my GKE cluster node pool to have 2 nodes during working hours but scale in to 0 nodes during night (non-working hours) as it is a dev environment and it is not used in this period.
When using AWS it is possible using Auto Scaling groups Scheduled actions and set it to the desired capacity (0-1-2 instances) but I want to know if there is something similar on GCP

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [GCP docs](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler#how_cluster_autoscaler_works) Cluster autoscaler works on a per-node pool basis. When you configure a node pool with cluster autoscaler, you specify a minimum and maximum size for the node pool.

It periodically checks the status of Pods and nodes, and takes action:

- If Pods are unschedulable because there are not enough nodes in the node pool, cluster autoscaler adds nodes, up to the maximum size of the node pool.
- If nodes are under-utilized, and all Pods could be scheduled even with fewer nodes in the node pool, Cluster autoscaler removes nodes, down to the minimum size of the node pool. If the node cannot be drained gracefully after a timeout period (currently 10 minutes), the node is forcibly terminated. The grace period is not configurable for GKE clusters.

Comment: But it is autoscaling based on resource utilization. I need scale based on time, something like defining a cron expression and scale out/in the number of nodes in that moment

Comment: @ORP autoscaling managed by the GKE Master node based on the resource utilization, master node scale up/down the number of node in a node pool

Comment: @ORP Have you seen this post about [Time based trigger on GKE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52262111/kubernetes-scaling-up-pods-by-time-based-trigger)? 
This [article](https://medium.com/symbl-ai-engineering-and-data-science/time-based-scaling-for-kubernetes-deployments-9ef7ada93eb7) might also help, both have the same idea in using a cron job as you said and then, using a script to modify the resources to have it scale up or down.